# Gradle build finished with 520 error(s) but APK generated successfully

Tags: android, gradle

every time i want to run or debug my app, gradle always builds with errors but successfully by studio.but when i want to generate by myself,it failed,so strange.

```
 android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jinjiang.computer.tianyi"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

       repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile files('F:/AndroidStudioProjects/TianYi/libs/Msc.jar')
        compile files('F:/AndroidStudioProjects/TianYi/libs/Sunflower.jar')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
        compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.14'
        compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.0.8'
    }
```

> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous
>   inner class 
> Error:(com.iflytek.cloud.a) that doesn't come with an
>   
> Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was
>   probably produced by a 
> Error:compiler that did not target the
>   modern .class file format. The recommended 
> Error:solution is to
>   recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   
> Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The
>   consequence of ignoring 
> Error:this warning is that reflective
>   operations on this class will incorrectly 
> Error:indicate that it
>   is *not* an inner class. 
> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses
>   attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   
> Error:(com.iflytek.cloud.b) that doesn't come with an
>   
> Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was
>   probably produced by a 
> Error:compiler that did not target the
>   modern .class file format. The recommended 
> Error:solution is to
>   recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   
> Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The
>   consequence of ignoring 
> Error:this warning is that reflective
>   operations on this class will incorrectly 
> Error:indicate that it
>   is *not* an inner class. 
> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses
>   attribute for an anonymous inner class
>
> ...
>
> Error:(com.iflytek.thridparty.T) that doesn't come with an
>   
> Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was
>   probably produced by a 
> Error:compiler that did not target the
>   modern .class file format. The recommended 
> Error:solution is to
>   recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   
> Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The
>   consequence of ignoring 
> Error:this warning is that reflective
>   operations on this class will incorrectly 
> Error:indicate that it
>   is *not* an inner class. 
> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses
>   attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   
> Error:(com.iflytek.thridparty.aA) that doesn't come with an
>   
> Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was
>   probably produced by a 
> Error:compiler that did not target the
>   modern .class file format. The recommended 
> Error:solution is to
>   recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   
> Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The
>   consequence of ignoring

etc.

Comment: You're not having errors, you're having warnings

Comment: what's the  warnings about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time ago I got rid of theses warnings by adding the following lines to my `proguard-rules.pro` file:

```
-keepattributes InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod
-dontoptimize
```